# getting too many collisions with hash_combine

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, hash

I'm using `boost::unordered_map` with a custom structure that is more or less a vector of integers and have a custom hash function that looks like this:

```
std::size_t seed = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < myvec.size(); ++i)
  boost::hash_combine(seed, myvec[i]);

return seed;
```

When `myvec` is of size 3 and I fill the hash with 1M elements 1:100 x 1:100 x 1:100 (so each element of `myvec` is an integer from 1 to 100) I get about 330,000 collisions.

Is it normal to get this many collisions and what can I do to avoid that?

Comment: By "collisions", I assume you mean they hash to the same `size_t` value?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think so, but more specifically - I'm counting buckets that have more than 1 element in the final `unordered_map`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. Boost's `hash_combine` function does poorly for this data set. You can test with [this code](http://codepad.org/rkll4HSQ) which shows almost 600,000 collisions for the one million test entries.

Here's a simple fix:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myvec.size(); ++i)
  boost::hash_combine(seed, myvec[i] * 2654435761);
```

The magic number is a prime close to 2^32 * (sqrt(5)-1)/2 -- see [Knuth](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9639/how-did-knuth-derive-a) for an explanation of why that works to expand the intervals.

Comment: thanks - that modification decreased the number of collisions but still more than 200000 buckets have more than 1 element; and another question - wouldn't this impact the performance significantly as it now has to do a few multiplications each time?

Comment: Buckets having more than one element is perfectly normal, it's part of how an unordered map works. As for the performance impact being "significant", I suppose it would depend on your application, but probably not. If it matters, compare several different hash functions and pick the one that works best in your particular application -- use live data if possible.